# Too many buffers hit+read during index scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I've 2 tables `User` and `Info`. I'm writing a simple query with inner join and inserting the result into an unlogged table.

```
INSERT INTO Result (
iProfileId,email,format,content
) 
SELECT
  COALESCE(N1.iprofileId, 0),
  Lower(N1.email),
  W0.format,
  W0.content
FROM
  Info W0,
  User N1
where
  (N1.iprofileId = W0.iId);
```

`Info` table has 30M rows and `User` table has 158M rows. Due to some reason, this query is taking too long on one of my prod setups. At first glance it looks like its reading/hitting too many buffers:

```
Insert on Result  (cost=152813.60..15012246.06 rows=31198136 width=1080) (actual time=5126063.502..5126063.502 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=128815094 read=6103564 dirtied=599445 written=2088037
   I/O Timings: read=2563306.517 write=570919.940
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=152813.60..15012246.06 rows=31198136 width=1080) (actual time=0.097..5060947.922 rows=31191937 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: (w0.iid = n1.iprofileid)
         Buffers: shared hit=96480126 read=5574864 dirtied=70745 written=2009998
         I/O Timings: read=2563298.981 write=562810.833
         ->  Index Scan using user_idx on info w0  (cost=0.56..2984094.60 rows=31198136 width=35) (actual time=0.012..246299.026 rows=31191937 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=481667 read=2490602 written=364347
               I/O Timings: read=178000.987 write=38663.457
         ->  Index Scan using profile_id on user n1  (cost=0.57..14938848.88 rows=158842848 width=32) (actual time=0.020..4718272.082 rows=115378606 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=95998459 read=3084262 dirtied=70745 written=1645651
               I/O Timings: read=2385297.994 write=524147.376
 Planning Time: 11.531 ms
 Execution Time: 5126063.577 ms
```

When I ran this query on a different setup but with similar tables and number of records, profile_id scan only used 5M pages(ran in 3m) whereas here it used(read+hit) 100M buffers(ran in 1.45h). When I checked using vacuum verbose this table only has 10M pages.

```
INFO:  "User": found 64647 removable, 109184385 nonremovable row versions in 6876625 out of 10546400 pages
```

This is one of the good runs but we've seen this query taking up to 4-5 hrs as well. My test system which ran in under 3 mins also had `iid` distributed among `profile_id` range. But it had fewer columns and indexes as compared to the prod system. What could be the reason for this slowness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution plan you are showing has a lot of dirtied and written pages. That indicates that the tables were freshly inserted, and your query was the first reader.

In PostgreSQL, the first reader of a new table row consults the *commit log* to see if that row is visible or not (did the transaction that created it commit?). It then sets flags in the row (the so-called hint bits) to save the next reader that trouble.

Setting the hint bits modifies the row, so the block is dirtied and has to be written to disk eventually. That writing is normally done by the checkpointer or the background writer, but they couldn't keep up, so the query had to clean out many dirty pages itself.

If you run the query a second time, it will be faster. For that reason, it is a good idea to `VACUUM` tables after bulk loading, which will also set the hint bits.

However, a large query like that will always be slow. Things you can try to speed it up further are:

- have lots of RAM and load the tables into shared buffers with `pg_prewarm`
- crank up `work_mem` in the hope to get a faster hash join
- `CLUSTER` the tables using the indexes, so that heap fetches become more efficient

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. This query runs 4-5 times a day and it still takes 1.5 hours to 5 hours each time. I tried running the vacuum but it didn't help much. Update runs once a day and it updates 3% of the table. I don't understand why profile_id index is reading 100M buffers(shared+hit) each time it is run.

Comment: Ok, so I ran clustering based on profile_id and it reduced the number of buffers hits to 5M(query finished in 3m).  It did not reduce the total number of pages in the table by a lot, I only had ~20% bloat. Now my question is, does the number of buffers read increase if the rows are scattered across pages as opposed to if they are sequential? I'm scanning almost the whole table so I must be reading same number of actual pages. Why are buffers reported so different?

Comment: Yes, definitely. If there are 50 rows in each page and the table is not clustered, the index scan will visit the same page 50 times. The page might even have dropped from the cache in between, if you have small `shared_buffers`. If the table is clustered, subsequent rows are likely found in the same block.

Comment: Ok, so you can include clustering suggestion in your answer and I'll accept it. Should I reduce my fill factor for avoiding this in future?

Comment: Done. No, `fillfactor` < 100 would make this slower, because the table will grow. Lower `fillfactor` is mostly useful for updates.

Comment: I'm asking because this table gets 3-4% updates daily and that is what led to this situation. When this was first created it was created using sequential profile_ids.

Comment: The updates were not a problem, otherwise you'd have more than 20% bloat. That is a totally normal figure and means everything is fine.